# when I try to get data using dbWriteTable & dbBulkCopy, I get this error

Tags: r, rsqlserver

I've just installed `rsqlserver` like so (no errors)

```
install_github('rsqlserver', 'agstudy',args = '--no-multiarch')
```

And created a connection to my database:

```
> library(rClr)
> library(rsqlserver)
```

Now when I try to get data using `dbWriteTable` & `dbBulkCopy`, I get this error:

```
Error in clrCall(sqlDataHelper, "GetConnectionProperty", conn, prop) : 
  Type:    System.MissingMethodException
Message: Method not found: 'System.Object System.Reflection.PropertyInfo.GetValue(System.Object)'.
Method:  System.Object GetConnectionProperty(System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.String)
Stack trace:
   at rsqlserver.net.SqlDataHelper.GetConnectionProperty(SqlConnection _conn, String prop)
```

Am I doing something wrong?